# Leaking joint/pipe. What product to use?

Tags: plumbing

[image]

Our “plumber” drilled hole in main down pipe (plastic) instead of in the ceramic main out pipe (Black). Probably good that he didn’t touch that!

Anyway, the product he used to seal the “joint” has degraded over last two months, and is now leaking. Short term, I need to re-seal. Wondering if anyone can tell me what product to use?

The flexi pipe is the out from the washing machine.

Many thanks

Comment: Get him back to do it properly.

Comment: That is a TOTALLY inappropriate way to connect a washer drain line to a waste pipe!  Even if it wasn't leaking, that could allow waste to backflow into your washer and possibly overflow it.  Either FIX it or get it fixed by a real plumber.  Whoever did this was incompetent!

Comment: This gives hack jobs a bad name.  The best product to fix this is called "NEW PLUMBER".

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've given a somewhat vague answer; if you add more pictures/diagrams of your setup then someone can probably give you a better one. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, fixing this isn't a "get the right stuff to apply to the join" situation, but a "completely redo the join using the correct method" situation. Your plumber did a complete hack job; you risk sewage leaking into your home, as well as backflow into your (I'm guessing) washing machine. And, any sort of caulk you apply will only work temporarily. And, what happens when you want to move the washing machine for service?

If this was done by a "real" plumber, then you should definitely get them back to do it right.

(I don't have the chops to recommend a full fix; perhaps someone else will add an answer that does.)